# Number eval issue python

Tags: python, sympy

I want to evaluate the following differential using the values in list y however I cant figure out what I am doing wrong. I am supposed to get 1.9256 for y=5, 1.9956 for y=10 and 2.1356 for y=20. What I'm trying to do is ask the user to input an equation with x as its variable, derive this equation with respect to x, ask the user to input as many values as he wants and evaluate the expression using these inputted values. Thanks for your help.

```
import sympy as sym
print('Sensitivity: ')
#exp = input('Enter the expression to find the sensitivity: ')
exp='(0.007*(x**2))+(1.8556*x)-1.8307'
#values=list(map(float,input('Enter the values at which you want to compute the sensitivity seperated by spaces: ').split())) 
values=[5,10,20]
x=sym.Symbol('x')      
differential=str(sym.diff(exp,x))
print(differential)
for i in y:
    expression=differential.replace(str(x),str(values))
    value=eval(expression)
    print('The sensitivity at',i,'is: ',value)
```

Comment: Why are you swapping x and y? What results do you actually get (vs. what you expect to get)?

Comment: I want to evaluate the expression that is derived with respect to x by certain values that the user inputs that are stored in a list called y

Comment: I get a different error from your code: `NameError: Name 'y' is not defined`. Make sure your question actually creates the specific problem you want to ask about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I believe you intended to write is:

```
import sympy as sym

exp='(0.007*(x**2))+(1.8556*x)-1.8307'
values=[5,10,20]
x=sym.Symbol('x')      
differential=str(sym.diff(exp,x))
print(differential)
for value in values:
    expression=differential.replace(str(x),str(value))
    result=eval(expression)
    print('The sensitivity at',value,'is: ',result)
```

...which emits as output:

```
The sensitivity at 5 is:  1.9256
The sensitivity at 10 is:  1.9956
The sensitivity at 20 is:  2.1356
```

---

Note the changes:

- We're iterating `for value in values` -- `values` exists, `y` does not.
- We're assigning the `eval` result to a separate variable (in this case, `result`)

This still is not by any means *good* code. Good code would not do string substitution to substitute values into code. Substituting `repr(value)` instead of `str(value)` would be at least somewhat less broken.